# ¿Error en enviar datos de restablecer contraseña PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Algo estoy realizando mal, al introducir datos de un usuario correcto y su cuenta activa, me muestra el mensaje de error de:

`¡Usuario con ese correo electrónico no existe!`

Pero al no introducir correo o usuario, es decir envió el campo `input` en blanco, me muestra el mensaje de:

```
¡Por favor, revise su correo electrónico para obtener un enlace de confirmación para completar su restablecimiento de contraseña!
```

Que estoy haciendo mal, el error viene desde aquí `if ($stmt->num_rows>0)` o cual es el error que ocasiona este fallo.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "require.php";

if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $email_require = 'Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
        } else {
            $email_require = 'Tu dirección de correo electrónico no es válida';
        }
    }
    $active = 1;
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, first_name, email_code FROM users WHERE email=? OR username=? AND active=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$email,$username,$active);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
        echo "¡Usuario con ese correo electrónico no existe!";
    } else {
        $stmt->bind_result($email_user, $first_name, $email_code);
        $stmt->fetch();

        echo '¡Por favor, revise su correo electrónico '.$email_user.' para obtener un enlace de confirmación para completar su restablecimiento de contraseña!';

        $to = $email_user;
        $subject = "Proceso para restablecer su contraseña";
        $message_body = 'Hola '.$first_name.',
        ¡Has solicitado restablecimiento de contraseña!

        Por favor, haga clic en este enlace para restablecer su contraseña.

        http://example/login-system/reset.php?email='.urlencode($email).'&key='.$email_code.'';
        mail($to, $subject, $message_body, 'example@example.com');
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="forgot.php" method="post">
         <input type="email" autocomplete="off" name="email"/>
         <input type="submit" name="formsubmitted" value="Reset" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Al enviar correo correcto.

```
¡Usuario con ese correo electrónico no existe!mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 1 [param_count] => 3 [field_count] => 3 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 2 )
```

Al enviar campo `input` vació.

```
¡Por favor, revise su correo electrónico para obtener un enlace de confirmación para completar su restablecimiento de contraseña!mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 3 [field_count] => 3 [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 2 )
```

Comment: es un problema de logica mi niña, ya que la condicion es verdadera pero tu le mandas el mensaje de que no es valido... cuando la condicion sea verdadera que quieres que haga el programa ?

Comment: Aparte del error que te indica @srJJ, tienes más errores de lógica en la forma en que controlas el flujo de los `if`... Por ejemplo, haces unas validaciones al principio y luego de esas validaciones ejecutas el código de la consulta SQL sí o sí. Debes organizar el código de tal forma que si el email no es válido por ejemplo, la consulta no se ejecute.

Comment: @A.Cedano es verdad, solo que me concetre en el problema principal y omiti el resto, he modificado la respuesta, gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo que la validación del input vacío lo hagas del lado del cliente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo tu codigo y entendiendo lo que pretendes, es un simple problema de logica, lo cual estan trocados, intenta de esta manera:

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_require = 'Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico';
} else {
    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $active = 1;
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, first_name, email_code FROM users WHERE email=? OR username=? AND active=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$email,$username,$active);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        //como los datos que pasas en los inputs concuerdan con la Base de datos te tare 1 fila con lo datos que pediste
        //es decir la condicion es verdadera
        if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
          //aqui debes hacer el proceso de recuperacion 
            $stmt->bind_result($email_user, $first_name, $email_code);
            $stmt->fetch();

            echo '¡Por favor, revise su correo electrónico '.$email_user.' para obtener un enlace de confirmación para completar su restablecimiento de contraseña!';

            $to = $email_user;
            $subject = "Proceso para restablecer su contraseña";
            $message_body = 'Hola '.$first_name.',
            ¡Has solicitado restablecimiento de contraseña!

            Por favor, haga clic en este enlace para restablecer su contraseña.

            http://example/login-system/reset.php?email='.urlencode($email).'&key='.$email_code.'';
            mail($to, $subject, $message_body, 'example@example.com');
        } else {
          //como los campos que envio estan vacion, entonces la base de datos nunca retornara ninguna fila
          //y es aqui donde captura el error 
            echo "¡Usuario con ese correo electrónico no existe!";
        }
    } else {
        $email_require = 'Tu dirección de correo electrónico no es válida';
    }
}
```

}

**NOTA** siguiendo el acertado comentario @A.Cedano he editado la **respuesta** la cual deja tu codigo deberia quedar asi, para que solo ejecute la consulta cuando el email sea valido

espero te sirva! me cuentas

Comment: Hola @srJJ gracias amigo, voy a ejecutar lo que usted me indica  :)

Comment: Disculpe, me puedes explicar lo que indica nando, en su respuesta, estoy haciendo mal el uso de esto `if ($stmt->num_rows>0)` que acción esta dando, alpaercer no es como lo pensaba, tal como lo indica nando en su respuesta.

Comment: El lo que esta tratando de decir que tambien puedes hacer uso de esa sentencia negandola `if(!$stmt->num_rows>0)` (tiene el signo de `!` precedido de la condicion) o invitiendola `($stmt->num_rows<0)` (tiene el operador `<` refiere inversion)

Comment: @Karla esta respuesta es correcta y más completa que la de Nando. Lo que Nando te indica es seguir con la lógica como la tenías, pero en vez de evaluar si es mayor que cero, evaluar que es menor (negando con `!`, que sirve para eso). Es lo mismo que te dice srJJ, pero al revés. Aparte de eso no estabas controlando bien los `if`. Prueba con el código que dice srJJ en esta respuesta. Debería funcionar así.

Comment: @Karla prueba y nos cuentas que sucede...

Comment: @srJJ Gracias amigo, funciona correctamente :)

Comment: De nada, siempre es un placer ayudar y aun mas con el apoyo del maestro @A.Cedano :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en `$stmt->num_rows>0`, si todo lo demás esta bien te devolverá 1 o mas registros depende como lo valides, de este modo tu condicional seria `($stmt->num_rows<0)` con esto le dices que si devolvió un registro o mas entra a la sentencia, también podrías negado `if(!$stmt->num_rows>0)`.

Cuando envías el input vació pasa las validaciones decido a que en tu tabla tal ves tengas registros de ese campo vaciós por lo cual te devuelve true

Saludos espero te sirva

Comment: Me puedes explicar con más detalle lo que me comentas amigo, no estoy comprendiendo, aparecer lo he estado mal interpretando aquella función, cual es verdadero o falso, yo pensaba que era de esta forma?? `if ($stmt->num_rows>0){falso}else{verdadero}`

Comment: A mi juicio solo niego las consultas cuando sea estrictamente necesario, ya que el `!` es casi inperceptible y en la depuracion puede dar dolores de cabeza

Comment: @Karla la interpretacion es: ´if ($stmt->num_rows>0){Verdadero}else{Falso}´