# ¿Cómo guardar la nueva contraseña restablecida PHP?

Tags: php

Con la ayuda de [srJJ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192321/error-en-enviar-datos-de-restablecer-contrase%C3%B1a-php) ahora ya puedo recibir en el correo del enlace de restablecer contraseña.

```
http://example.com/login-system/reset.php?email=example%40gmail.com&key=523db8c57a3d17d0860fa705c4c24ec62efc0c68f2f1443e39938361424099f1
```

A pesar de que los datos son correctos, no me muestra el formulario para ingresar la nueva contraseña, mostrándome el siguiente mensaje.

```
¡Ingresó una URL inválida para restablecer la contraseña!
```

Este es mi archivo `reset.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
include "require.php";

if (isset($_GET['email']) && preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/', $_GET['email'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
}
if (isset($_GET['key']) && (strlen($_GET['key']) == 64)) {
    $key = $_GET['key'];
}

if (isset($email) && isset($key)) {
    //$email = $con->escape_string($_GET['email']);
    //$key = $con->escape_string($_GET['key']);
    $active_defaul = 1;

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND email_code=? AND active=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$email,$key,$active_defaul);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    //if ($result->num_rows == 0 )
    if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
        echo "¡Ingresó una URL inválida para restablecer la contraseña!";
    } else {
        echo '
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="reset_password.php" method="post">
     <label>New Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"/>
    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password_again" autocomplete="off"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="'.$email.'">
        <input type="submit" name="form_reset" value="Guardar contraseña" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>';
    }

} else {
    echo "¡Acceso denegado!";
}
?>
```

Y este sería mi archivo donde se enviará la contraseña aunque sería mejor hacerlo todo en el mismo archivo `reset.php`

Mi archivo `reset_password.php`

```
session_start();
include "require.php";

if (isset($_POST['form_reset'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $hash_password = password_hash($password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH);

    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET password= ? WHERE email=? OR username=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $hash_password,$email,$email);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        header("location: correcto.php")
    } else {
        header("location: error.php");
    }

}
```

No puedo comprobar si existe errores en `reset_password.php` porque no me esta validando el archivo `reset.php`, estoy trabajando de manera individual los archivos una vez que observe que si funciona todo, lo implementare con `AJAX` y luego mediante jQuery o javascript evitare enviar peticiones al servidor en datos no validos en el formulario.

Comment: ¿Parece que tienes un serio problema con la lógica :-) ?  ¿Qué pasa si lo pones así: `if ($stmt->num_rows==0) {`   ...?

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí, En serio, por eso decía en mi anterior pregunta que me explicaran más sobre ello :(

Comment: Como ya sabrás `num_rows` devuelve la cantidad de filas que trajo la consulta. Al hacer esto: `if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
        echo "¡Ingresó una URL inválida para restablecer la contraseña!";` estás implementando una *lógica al revés*, porque le dices al código: *si la consulta trajo alguna fila, di que la URL es inválida*, cuando debería ser lo contrario, si la consulta trae filas es porque en efecto encontró una URL válida. Por tanto, puedes hacer una comparación basándote en `if ($stmt->num_rows==0) {`

Comment: @A.Cedano Ahora entiendo :) voy a enviar los datos haber si se actualizan :)

Comment: No Karla, si lees mi comentario anterior con un poco de calma entenderás que no, que es una lógica inversa lo que aplicas al hacer `if ($stmt->num_rows>0)`

Comment: @A.Cedano Amigo, no me actualiza la contraseña que estoy haciendo mal, aparte de lo que estaba mal, pero que ya he entendido con su comentario :)

Comment: ¿Sigue diciendo lo mismo el código o dice otra cosa?

Comment: @A.Cedano No ahora no me muestra ningún mensaje de error, porque los datos son correctos me está mostrando el formulario, pero al pulsar enviar reviso la base de datos pero no me muestra ningún cambio.

Comment: Hay que revisar ese código entonces. Vamos a ver... ¿No te hace ni una ni otra de estas redirecciones: `if($stmt->execute()){
        header("location: correcto.php")
    } else {
        header("location: error.php");
    }`?

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya me restablece la contraseña, me había olvidado una comilla en los `header` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya sabrás `num_rows` devuelve la cantidad de filas que trajo la consulta.

Al hacer esto:

```
if ($stmt->num_rows>0) { 
    echo "¡Ingresó una URL inválida para restablecer la contraseña!";
```

estás implementando una *lógica al revés*, porque le dices al código: *si la consulta trajo alguna fila, di que la URL es inválida*, cuando debería ser lo contrario, si la consulta trae filas es porque en efecto encontró una URL válida.

Por tanto, puedes hacer una comparación basándote en

```
if ($stmt->num_rows==0) {
```

De todos modos, has de saber que el mejor método para saber si hay filas en una tabla con un determinado criterio es `COUNT`, sobre todo cuando lo único que necesitas en ese contexto es saber si hay datos o no. Pero puedes profundizar en eso cuando resuelvas tu problema con la *lógica* :-)

Comment: Gracias amigo, ahora me quedó muy claro sobre el uso de `if ($stmt->num_rows>0){}` ahora tengo un problema más grave, un problema de seguridad [escribí una nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192360/grave-agujero-de-seguridad-al-permitir-restablecer-la-contrase%C3%B1a-php). Amigo ya me quedo claro sobre aquel uso, me puedes dar un ejemplo, en un simple comentario, sobre esto `if ($stmt->num_rows==0) {}` que hace, un ejemplo como anteriormente me explicaste.