# ¿Evitar enviar correo de restauración de contraseña a un usuario no activo?

Tags: php, mysqli

Probé restablecer contraseña de un usuario inactivo, que aún no verifico su email, y al enviar aquel formulario, me indica que revise el email para restablecer la contraseña, pero no debería enviar el correo porque el usuario esta inactivo.

Entonces como le puedo agregar otro mensaje personalizado, si el usuario no esta activo, decirle, por favor active su cuenta, si tiene problema en activar reenvié la verificación en el siguiente formulario(un enlace).

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_require = 'Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico';
} else {
    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $active = 1;
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, first_name, email_code FROM users WHERE email=? OR username=? AND active=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$email,$username,$active);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        //como los datos que pasas en los inputs concuerdan con la Base de datos te tare 1 fila con lo datos que pediste
        //es decir la condicion es verdadera
        if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
          //aqui debes hacer el proceso de recuperacion 
            $stmt->bind_result($email_user, $first_name, $email_code);
            $stmt->fetch();

            echo '¡Por favor, revise su correo electrónico '.$email_user.' para obtener un enlace de confirmación para completar su restablecimiento de contraseña!';

            $to = $email_user;
            $subject = "Proceso para restablecer su contraseña";
            $message_body = 'Hola '.$first_name.',
            ¡Has solicitado restablecimiento de contraseña!

            Por favor, haga clic en este enlace para restablecer su contraseña.

            http://example.com/login-system/reset.php?email='.urlencode($email).'&key='.$email_code.'';
            mail($to, $subject, $message_body, 'From: example@alo.com');
        } else {
          //como los campos que envio estan vacion, entonces la base de datos nunca retornara ninguna fila
          //y es aqui donde captura el error 
            echo "¡Usuario con ese correo electrónico no existe!";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Tu dirección de correo electrónico no es válida';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: no envies el status en la consulta, y al mostrar el mensaje sabras si esta activo o no

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, en tu **BD** debes de tener la condición de activo y no activo. Solo comprueba el estado en que esta el usuario, si esta inactivo mandas una excepción y sino realizas el proceso de forma normal.

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow entonces el error está ahí, pero que extraño, se supone que los datos enviados recibidos del formulario debía pasar por las condiciones, cumplió todo excepto el active porque el valor que tiene es 0 y se está pidiendo un valor de 1, algo no me cuadra :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Debemos modificar la instrucción `SELECT` para recuperar la columna `[active]`.
- Una vez recuperado el valor de la columna `[active]`, evaluar su valor.

Aquí tienes la solución implementada:

```
<?

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_require = 'Por favor, ingrese su correo electrónico';
} else {
    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT email, first_name, email_code, active FROM users WHERE email=? OR username=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssi",$email,$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        //como los datos que pasas en los inputs concuerdan con la Base de datos te tare 1 fila con lo datos que pediste
        //es decir la condicion es verdadera
        if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
          //aqui debes hacer el proceso de recuperacion 
            $stmt->bind_result($email_user, $first_name, $email_code, $active);
            $stmt->fetch();

            // Usuario no activo?
            if (!$active) {
               echo 'Por favor active su cuenta. Si tiene problema en activar reenvié la verificación en el siguiente formulario. http://example.com/login-system/activate.php?email='.urlencode($email);
            }
            // Recuperar contraseña
            else
            {
                    echo '¡Por favor, revise su correo electrónico '.$email_user.' para obtener un enlace de confirmación para completar su restablecimiento de contraseña!';

                    $to = $email_user;
                    $subject = "Proceso para restablecer su contraseña";
                    $message_body = 'Hola '.$first_name.',
                    ¡Has solicitado restablecimiento de contraseña!

                    Por favor, haga clic en este enlace para restablecer su contraseña.

                    http://example.com/login-system/reset.php?email='.urlencode($email).'&key='.$email_code.'';
                    mail($to, $subject, $message_body, 'From: example@alo.com');
            }

        } else {
          //como los campos que envio estan vacion, entonces la base de datos nunca retornara ninguna fila
          //y es aqui donde captura el error 
            echo "¡Usuario con ese correo electrónico no existe!";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Tu dirección de correo electrónico no es válida';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hola @dperezv.com voy a seguir las indicaciones de su respuesta, voy a verificarlo en unos momentos gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Bajo mi experiencia reservaría tres campos en la tabla users para este caso:

- (boolean) **active** - Para marcar si un usuario está activo/inactivo (es decir, puede hacer login).
- (boolean) **validate** - Para marcar si un usuario ha verificado su correo electrónico.
- (text) **token** - Para almacenar hash de restaurar contraseña/validar email.

Entonces:

1. Al registrarse un usuario se guarda un hash en **token**. Se fija **active**=1 y **validate**=0. (El usuario ya puede hacer login pero su email no ha sido validado).
2. El usuario hace click sobre el link de validación del email. Se marca **token**=null, **active**=1 y **validate**=1.
3. El usuario olvida su contraseña: Se guarda un **token**, **active**=1 y **validate**=1. (Si se da el caso de token!=null y validate=1 ya podemos identificar este caso en una query)
4. Hay que prohibir el login a usuario: se marca **active**=0.
5. El usuario edita/cambia en su perfil su cuenta de email: se guarda un **token**, **active**=1 y **validate**=0.

Espero te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Hola @XanPena lo que me has indicado me sirve para esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192360/grave-agujero-de-seguridad-al-permitir-restablecer-la-contraseña-php pero me gustaría que me ayudarás con ejemplos, te agradecería, creo que deberías migrar está respuesta para esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/192360/grave-agujero-de-seguridad-al-permitir-restablecer-la-contraseña-php